# UIWebView disable zooming programmatically

Tags: xcode, ios, uiwebview

Is it possible to disable zooming (pinching or tapping) programmatically for a UIWebView?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just set `scalesPageToFit` to NO and you're done.

> If YES, the webpage is scaled to fit and the user can zoom in and zoom out. If NO, user zooming is disabled. The default value is NO.

Comment: Has no effect for me in iOS 5.